# importxml in Google spreadsheet and returning a Google search result

Tags: xml, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, google-search

I am trying to upload a result of a Google Search into my Google spreadsheet using `importxml` and the code that used to work doesn't anymore. I have

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/search?q=site:[query]&num=100&start=1","//cite")
```

My error message is

> Could not fetch url: `https://www.google.com/search?q=site:[query]&num=100&start=1`

Can someone tell me why this doesn't work anymore?

Answer (score 4):

Google has lately been blocking search requests made from both Apps Scripts and Google Sheets though the requests are made from one of their own IPs. They probably do this to prevent scraping.

Comment: So how do we overcome it?